# Pushing back the load time of specific ASP.NET elements

Tags: javascript, asp.net, events

I'm having trouble with the drop-down navigation being flattened and completely shown for several seconds while a page is loading. It usually only shows on pages that are more info-heavy, so I'm assuming its loading the navigation really fast.

Is there a way to delay loading the navigation bar until after all of the info is loaded? I tried writing a javascript onLoad function, but that just led me to a bunch of form errors for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple method could be wrapping your navigation in an HTML element with attribute `display:none;`, then when the DOM is loaded you could remove the attribute. I think that should keep it hidden from the beginning.

Comment: is there a reason this code wouldn't be executing? I think there is something wrong with the way I call the onload command. Sorry, I hardly ever use javascript. '<span id="menuTest" style="display:none;" onload="this.style.removeAttribute(display)">'

Comment: @Jordan Foreman - I would look into using the `window.onload` rather than the span's onload function.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'll see where I can get with that